# Colorplot of portion 2D array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, charts

H=[[0,0,0,0][0,1,2,3][0,3,4,3][0,5,2,3]]

Are there any ways to plot H[i in range(1,4)][j in range(1,4)]
with x-axis in range(1,4) and y-axis in range(1,4)?

[image: plot picture]

I want to cut of those darkest parts of the graph which shows zero

I've tried

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

H=[[0,0,0,0][0,1,2,3][0,3,4,3][0,5,2,3]]
V=np.array([[H[i][j] for j in range(1,4)] for i in range(1,4)])

plt.imshow(V)
plt.colorbar(orientation='vertical')
plt.show()
```

but the plot showed H[1][1] on (x,y)=(0,0). I wanna make it show each H[i][j] on (i,j).
I've been searching for a long time but I couldn't find the solution.
Please help

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking to change. You share an image and seem to want the bottom 3x3 region, which the code seems to plot. What do you currently get and what is your desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can replace 0 by `np.nan`:

```
# Setup
H =[[0,0,0,0], [0,1,2,3], [0,3,4,3], [0,5,2,3]]
V = np.array(H)

# Create a new array where 0 is now NaN
U = np.where(V==0, np.nan, V)

# Display the result
plt.imshow(U)
plt.colorbar(orientation='vertical')
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
>>> V
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 3, 4, 3],
       [0, 5, 2, 3]])

>>> U
array([[nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan,  1.,  2.,  3.],
       [nan,  3.,  4.,  3.],
       [nan,  5.,  2.,  3.]])
```

[image]

Comment: If you prefer remove rows and columns where values is 0, you can do `U = V[:, V.any(axis=0)][V.any(axis=1), :]`